# How to make an SFTP connection with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, sftp, delphi-xe6

I need to do a **file transfer** process inside my software, and the files are a little **sensitive**, so I would like to do via **SFTP**, so I have researched that there are some components (all the payments I've researched) that make use protocol.

I would like to know if you have a **free component**, or how to do it **manually**, if possible.

---

<sup>*Sorry, translated via google translate.*</sup>

Comment: I don't understand the question. What exactly are you asking.

Comment: FTPS which is FTP over SSL, but not SFTP is supported by the included Indy components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Indy sftp component. 
The Indy components are included in delphi since a while.

Alternativley you could try these activex method: 
https://www.activexperts.com/network-component/howto/sftp/delphi/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going to study.

Comment: Link only answers with component recommendations aren't a good fit here

Comment: Sure, its not perfect, but it gives him an idea, where to look. 
i will edit my answer with a more indeepth content ^^

Comment: Like I said, this doesn't fit as an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: if you have less than 50 points of reputation, you are not allowed to write comments. the only way to give inputs are answers. Its not my system. Therefore i can only follow these rules.

Comment: You didn't follow the rules. If you can't make comments, then you shouldn't write comments as an answer. That is the rule.

Comment: i did not realized that my asnwer could be counted as a comment. 
since the question opener has accepted my answer it looks like it was one.

Comment: No, the people asking the questions often don't understand how the site works either. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174

Comment: This is wrong. Indy doesn't have any SFTP client  :-(